# Convert string into Hashes of symbol and integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to convert any given string of this format: `a = "a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5"` into hash of symbol (key) and integer (value).

Expected input is `{:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}` in this case.

This is what I have:

```
def hash_it(str)
  str.split(", ").map{|s| s.split("=")}.to_h
end
```

`hash_it(str)` returns `{"a"=>"2", "b"=>"3", "c"=>"4", "d"=>"5"}`. Close, but not quite. I am not sure how to turn the key into symbol and value into integer. I can convert them separately:

```
str.split(", ").map{|s| s.split("=")}.map{|n| n[0].to_sym}
#=> [:a, :b, :c, :d]
str.split(", ").map{|s| s.split("=")}.map{|n| n[1].to_i}
#=> [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But I can't put them together for the intended purpose.

How can I convert any given string in the format `"a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5"` into a hash of symbol-inter key-value `{:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}`?

Comment: It's perhaps worthwhile noting that, if `a` is your array, `eval "{ #{a.gsub(/\w+/,':\1') } }" #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably do it this way:

```
str = "a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5"
str.scan(/(\w+)=(\d+)/).map {|k,v| [ k.to_sym, v.to_i ] }.to_h
```

The `scan` just extracts each key-value pair, and the rest ought to be self-explanatory.

Comment: actually thought that some regex will work nicer here

Comment: While `scan` is a great tool, it also assumes your data is pristine. Any junk in the input is ignored, which might be desired behaviour or a real problem. Just a caveat.

Comment: @tadman Certainly. This is true of all of the solutions posted here—and really any solution that we could come up with, given the scant information provided by the OP. My solution, for example, may fail if there's unexpected whitespace on either side of the `=`; solutions using `split` may fail with unexpected trailing or duplicate delimiters.

Answer (score 2):

You were so close! The following will fix/extend your attempt slightly:

```
a = "a=2, b=3, c=4, d=5"

def hash_it(str)
  str.split(", ").map{|s| s.split("=")}.map{|n| [n[0].to_sym, n[1].to_i]}.to_h
end

hash_it(a) #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}
```

Comment: No need for the `syms = ` part since this is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String.class_eval do 
  def hashing
      self.split("#{oper1}").map{|s| [ s.split("#{oper2}")[0].strip.to_sym,s.split("#{oper2}")[1].to_i]}.to_h
  end
end
```

"YOUR STRING".hashing
and if you want it to user ", =" as default and others in another places do this

```
String.class_eval do 
  def hashing(oper1= ',', oper2= '=')
     self.split(oper1.to_s).map{|s| [ s.split(oper2.to_s)[0].strip.to_sym,s.split(oper2.to_s)[1].to_i]}.to_h
  end
end

"YOUR STRING ".hashing
#or 
"ANOTHER SRTING".hashing("|", "!") # for another split operators.
```

hope it helps.

Comment: The blind `rescue` statement here is really bad form, it suppresses errors and doesn't provide a whole lot of help. What exceptions are you expecting that code to generate?

Comment: What is `"#{oper1}"`? Are you trying to anticipate non-string arguments? If not, this is totally pointless and you should just use `oper1`. If so, why not just do `oper1.to_s`?

Answer (score 0):

```
def hashify(str)
  str.strip.split(/\s*(?:=|,\s)\s*/).each_slice(2).map { |k,v| [k.to_sym, v.to_i] }.to_h
end

str = " a = 2, b=3 , c= 4, d =5 "
hashify str
  #=> {:a=>"2", :b=>"3", :c=>"4", :d=>"5"}
```

The `split` operation reads, "split on an equals sign or a comma followed by a space, together with any surrounding whitespace".

The steps are as follows.

```
s = str.strip
  #=> "a = 2, b=3 , c= 4, d =5"
a = s.split(/\s*(?:=|,\s)\s*/)
  #=> ["a", "2", "b", "3", "c", "4", "d", "5"] 
e = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "2", "b", "3", "c", "4", "d", "5"]:each_slice(2)>
```

We can see the values that will generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [["a", "2"], ["b", "3"], ["c", "4"], ["d", "5"]]
```

Continuing,

```
f = e.map { |k,v| [k.to_sym, v.to_i] }
  #=> [[:a, 2], [:b, 3], [:c, 4], [:d, 5]] 
f.to_h
  #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4, :d=>5}
```

Comment: I believe the OP would like the values of the hash to be numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @sagarpandya82. Will fix.